# geometry line intersection with polygon returns null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, gis, geospatial

I'm trying to set a column based on the result of a line midpoint intersection with a polygon. I know I can call the line midpoint with something like

```
  X_Coord = SHAPE.STPointN(SHAPE.STNumPoints()/2).STX ,  
  Y_Coord = SHAPE.STPointN(SHAPE.STNumPoints()/2).STY
```

but how to pass that to

```
update GRSM_ROADS
set QuadName = USGS_24K_TOPOMAP_BOUNDARIES.NAME
from  GRSM_ROADS
inner join USGS_24K_TOPOMAP_BOUNDARIES
on dbo.GRSM_ROADS.Location_ID = GRSM_ROADS.Location_ID
where (USGS_24K_TOPOMAP_BOUNDARIES.SHAPE.STIntersects(dbo.GRSM_ROADS.shape) = 1);
```

is a mystery. I've tried stcontains and stintersects, which runs, but the output is null, indicating that I'm not correctly determining when or where the line midpoint intersects the polygon.

SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

```
where (USGS_24K_TOPOMAP_BOUNDARIES.SHAPE.STIntersection(dbo.GRSM_ROADS.shape).STDimension() = 1);
```

Stdimension solved it!